# Ionic Capacitor IOS Only Works With Livereload

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, capacitor

In my ionic capacitor ios app, the app works just fine on a web browser using `ionic serve`. When I try running `ionic capacitor run ios`, that is successful but when I build the app I get this:

[image: not working console]

While that looks like a lot, you can see that at the end it says Webview failed to load and the request timed out. On my phone, all I see is the splash screen.

Instead, when I run `ionic cap run ios -l --external`, I get this:

[image: working console with livereload]

In this console, the same warning messages happen, but it says "onscript loading complete" and then the actual app works.

I have looked through many StackOverflow + github pages offering help for this issue. From this [issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/126), I made sure that my phone and computer were on the same wifi. Anyone experienced this error before/knows what to do? This code has worked in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue! The app was trying to connect to a server that did not exist. I needed to remove the `server` field in `capacitor.config.json`. I cut out that json field and then ran `ionic cap run ios`, and the code worked.

Please comment if you are still experiencing this issue